# Ошибка JavaScript error occured in the main process : Compass

Tags: mongodb

Когда запускаю mongoDB client application Compass 1.13.1, получаю ошибку: [image]

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Варианты решений](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50993658/8370915)

---

1. Открыть диспетчер задач и закрыть запущенный клиент приложения Compass под названием `"The MongoDB GUI"` ,  `"MongoDBCompassCommunity"` и тд. (перед этим, желательно, отключиться в самом Compass, а не закрывать напрямую, нажав на крестик). - **этот вариант в 99% случаев решает проблему.**
2. Перезапустить Windows, затем открыть снова клиент.
3. Переустановить клиент, установив более свежую версию программы.
4. По пути `\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.13.1\resources` удалить файл под названием `app.asar`, перед этим скопировав где-то его копию(!) (в моем случае это был рабочий стол). Потом опять вставьте файл `app.asar` в то же место `\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.13.1\resources` и просто перезапустите Compass.